# Extra whitespace on top of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

This is my preamble that im using to format my document

```latex
% Package Inclusions
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft} % To customize the table of contents

% Images
\graphicspath{{/home/siddharthakhanal/MEGA/College/4th Semester/Operating System/case study/linux case study/images}}

% Page Formatting
\geometry{a4paper,portrait,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1.25in}

% References
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

% Set line spacing
\setstretch{1.5}

% Title formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{18}\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

% Configure figure caption formatting
\DeclareCaptionFormat{figureformat}{\centering\bfseries\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=figureformat, justification=centering, singlelinecheck=false}

% Configure table caption formatting
\DeclareCaptionFormat{tableformat}{\centering\bfseries\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[table]{format=tableformat, justification=centering, singlelinecheck=false, position=above}

% Setting up spacing between header and top
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{1cm}

% Set section heading formats
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\bfseries\uppercase}{Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

% Set figure and table captions
\captionsetup{font={bf,small},labelfont=bf,labelsep=period}


% For setting paragraph spacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}


% \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering\bfseries\normalfont\Large Table of Contents}
```

This is my main.tex file

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\input{preambles/preambles.tex}


\begin{document}

\include{chapters/coverpage}

\tableofcontents

% \pagenumbering{roman}
\include{chapters/1.introduction}
\include{chapters/2.overview}
\include{chapters/3.process_and_treads}
\include{chapters/4.memory_management}
\include{chapters/5.io}
\include{chapters/6.filesystem}
\include{chapters/7.security}

\printbibliography[title=refrences]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Refrences}


\end{document}
```

Im new to latex and I don't know what is going wrong here,when im rendering the toc it's adding extra white space of the top of it but it doesn't add extra spaces in the chapters

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Off-topic: The `times` font package is obsolete and deprecated. Don't use it. In its place, do load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved if you don't load the `tocloft` package and you use `\MakeUppercase` command instead of `\uppercase`. Try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{1cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\filcenter\fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Title}
\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is *not* necessary to stop loading the `tocloft` package. Instead, just load it with the option `titles`, i.e., run `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.

Comment: It's working thank you